# Comments not displaying

Tags: comments

This is very strange.

Comments are only displaying for a content type called "Issue" for roles that have the Comment permission "Administer comments and comment settings". I set the "View comments" permission for all roles. All the other content types display the comments properly to all roles. Somehow this content type is corrupted. Has anyone seen behavior like this? Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the node_comment_statistics table. When I first created the content type I selected "close comments". When I changed it later to have comments, it never put an entry into node_comment_statistics. So we had to go in there manually and put in an entry from the node.

Answer (score 2):

First verify that the Issue type isn't set to hide comments. If comments exist but are hidden, only admins will see them. A path something like this: `/admin/structure/types/manage/issue`, and go to the 'Comment settings' tab at the bottom.

Also, you might go to `/admin/reports/status/rebuild` and rebuild the permissions cache.

Comment: Hi Paul, I did what you said and no luck. Comment settings are open and permissions have been rebuilt.